# Как добавить свой текст на график Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, google-chart

Как можно в график добавить свой текст перед первой отрисовкой графика. Пример на картинке. И чтобы когда скачиваешь картинку методом `chart.getImageURI()`, текст тоже оставался

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в API такого не предусмотренно, а если и вывести это посредством манимпуляций с SVG, то не будет включаться в результат при вызове getImageURI. Либо выводить надпись посредством HTML, а при необходимости вывода изображения использовать [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg), но тут уже без поддержки старых браузеров и необходимостью писать кучу кода. А чем не устраивают встроенные заголовки?

Comment: @XelaNimed есть необходимость добавлять лого сайта внизу графика

Comment: В этом случае, на мой взгляд, прямая манипуляция SVG избыточна, т.к. она не принесёт никаких преимуществ, а код усложнит сильно, особенно при использовании различных типов графиков. Просто добавляйте лого как HTML, а при необходимости сохранять изображение обрабатывайте изображение без непосредственного вывода результата getImageURI.